# RSS feed reader plugin for Internet Explorer 6

Tags: rss, internet-explorer-6

When I tried to access RSS feed on Internet Explorer 6.0, it is showing raw RSS code. So I installed a RSS reader application such as feed reader. But although I can access the feed via the installed application, I was wondering if the IE6 problem could be overcome by any plugins.

Does installing plugins like blogbot ensure that IE6 behaves like further versions, or do I still have to manually add rss link to the installed readers?

I wish for my application to behave consistently on all browsers (which I know is too much to ask).

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

The best thing is to install a plugin called Firefox.  Just forget about IE 6

http://www.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/fx/

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

As you can see only 1.1% of the people who browse on the Internet use IE 6.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. But those 1.1% are crazy enough to complain instead of upgrading

Comment: Yeah and If you continue to satisfy their complains they will never advance to a modern browser. Isuggest you to open youtube.com with IE 6 and you will see what will happen. :) They are doing it, so there must be a reason don't you yhing so.